# facet_grid showing composition in percent with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid, aesthetics

I'm trying to get a facet-grid of my data-frame.

The purpose is to summarize the composition (in percent) of each clades (A, B, C, D, E, F) for every individuals (n=24).

Also the sum of each clade is not 100%, but ultimately really close to it.
None of the individuals got Clade B or F.

Here is my R script :

```
library(scales)
library(reshape)
library(ggplot2)

#Add an id variable for the filled regions
X_clade$ind <- factor(X_clade$ind)
X_clade$days <- factor(X_clade$days)
X_clade$temperature <- factor(X_clade$temperature)
X_clade$D <- NULL
Clade <- c(X_clade$A, X_clade$B, X_clade$C, X_clade$E, X_clade$F)
Abundance= 100*cumsum(Clade)/sum(Clade)
str(X_clade)
Abundance
hist(Clade$A)

#subset
file.29<-X_clade[(X_clade$days == 29),]
file.65<-X_clade[(X_clade$days == 65),]
file.53<-X_clade[(X_clade$days == 53),]

#install.packages("wesanderson")
library(wesanderson)
plot_bar(X_clade)

file.29$B <- NULL
file.29$F <- NULL
seq(0.1,1,by=0.1)

p1<-ggplot(file.29,aes(x = ind, y=Abundance,fill = Clade)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill",stat = "identity") +    
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())  +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.border=element_rect(fill=NA),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_text(colour="black",size=11),
        axis.text.y=element_text(colour="black",size=11),
        axis.title =element_blank()) + guides(fill=FALSE) +
  facet_grid(days~temperature,scales="free_x")
p1

p_1M=ggplot(file.29,aes(x = ind, y=Abundance,fill = Clade)) 
p_1M

p2<-ggplot(file.53,aes(x = ind, y=Abundance,fill = Clade)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill",stat = "identity") +  
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())  +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.border=element_rect(fill=NA),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        strip.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_text(colour="black",size=11),
        axis.text.y=element_text(colour="black",size=11),
        axis.title =element_blank()) +guides(fill=FALSE) +
  facet_grid(days~temperature,scales="free_x")
p2

p3<-ggplot(file.65,aes(x = ind, y=Abundance,fill = Clade)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill",stat = "identity") +  
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())  +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.border=element_rect(fill=NA),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        strip.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_text(colour="black",size=11),
        axis.text.y=element_text(colour="black",size=11),
        axis.title =element_blank()) + guides(fill=FALSE) +
  facet_grid(days~temperature,scales="free_x")
p3

library(gridExtra)

grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, nrow=3)
```

but for each plot (p1,p2,p3), i get the same error message : Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (8): x, y, fill.

Every insight on how to resolve this issue would be lovely ! As I am sure I'm not far away from it. 
But still, all the way stuck tho !

All my best

Homère

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a version that combines `purrr` with `cowplot` to make a list of plots and arrange them together. I'm mimicking a `facet_grid` by splitting the data on `temperature`, making separate columns of plots with `facet_wrap`. Using `imap`, I get the name of each of the split data frames—the temperature—and use this for titles. Then I do some slightly hacky things to extract the legend, remove the legend from both plots, make the strip text on the left plot invisible, and plot them all alongside each other.

```r
library(tidyverse)


df2 <- df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(days, temperature, ind), as.factor) %>%
  gather(key = group, value = value, -ind, -days, -temperature) %>%
  mutate(value = value / 100)

plots <- df2 %>%
  split(.$temperature) %>%
  imap(function(dat, temp) {
    ggplot(dat, aes(x = ind, y = value, fill = group)) +
      geom_col() +
      scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
      scale_fill_discrete(drop = T) +
      labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
      facet_wrap(~ days, ncol = 1, scales = "free_x", strip.position = "right") +
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 0, face = "italic"), 
            plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "italic")) +
      ggtitle(paste0(temp, "°C"))
  })
```

For example, the first column of plots looks like this:

```r
plots[[1]]
```

[image]

I made the strip text on the first column white to match the strip background, because I wanted it to still take up some space (so the columns would still have the same width) but not be visible.

```r
legend <- cowplot::get_legend(plots[[1]])
no_legends <- plots %>% map(~. + theme(legend.position = "none"))
no_legends[[1]] <- no_legends[[1]] + theme(strip.text = element_text(color = "white"))
```

Using `cowplot` and following [one of its vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/shared_legends.html), I made one grid of the two plots without legends, and a second grid of that first grid plus the legend, and adjust the relative widths to fit nicely. There's a lot of spacing and tweaking you can do from here.

```r
two_plots <- cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = no_legends)
cowplot::plot_grid(two_plots, legend, rel_widths = c(2, 0.25))
```

[image]

Created on 2018-05-25 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Hello Camille, I runned it and it's perfect. That's really nice of you ! A quick follow, I would like to change colors of each Clade (A,B,C,E,F) for a wesanderson palette, "IsleofDogs2".

Comment: You can add `scale_fill_*`, where `*` is whatever the name of the fill function is. I haven't used that package, but it should ship with some sort of scales like that, I'd assume

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to plot the data using `facet_wrap` turn off the strip labels and add desired labels using inkscape or photoshop.

```
library(tidyverse)
d %>% 
  gather(k, v, -days, -ind, -temperature) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(ind), y=v, fill = k)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(x, "%"))  +
  facet_wrap(~temperature + days, scales="free_x", dir = "v", ncol=2) + 
  theme(strip.text = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

Or try this

```
p1 <- d %>% 
  gather(k, v, -days, -ind, -temperature) %>% 
  filter(days == 29) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(ind), y=v, fill = k)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(x, "%"))  +
  facet_grid(days~temperature, scales="free_x")+
  xlab("") + 
  theme(legend.position = "none")

p2 <- d %>% 
  gather(k, v, -days, -ind, -temperature) %>% 
  filter(days == 53) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(ind), y=v, fill = k)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(x, "%"))  +
  facet_grid(days~temperature, scales="free_x")+
  xlab("") + 
  theme(strip.text.x = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none")

p3 <- d %>% 
  gather(k, v, -days, -ind, -temperature) %>% 
  filter(days == 65) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(ind), y=v, fill = k)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(x, "%"))  +
  facet_grid(days~temperature, scales="free_x")+
  theme(strip.text.x = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none")

p4 <- d %>% 
  gather(k, v, -days, -ind, -temperature) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(ind), y=v, fill = k)) +
  geom_col() +
  theme_void()

library(cowplot)         
cowplot::plot_grid(plot_grid(p1, p2, p3, ncol = 1), get_legend(p4), rel_widths = c(0.9,0.1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jimbou, looks really nice indeed. I prefer the second option. Really appreciated your input !

Comment: @Homère Please consider to accept the answer if you are convinced.